# CakePhp: About Views

Tags: php, cakephp

What is the difference between to these in cake php?

```
$this->fetch('title'); 




$this->extend('/Common/view');

$this->element('shop/cart.ctp');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- fetch() is used mainly in layout file to output a block of content.
- extend() is used to extend view. which allows you to wrap one view in
  another.
- element() is used to group an reusable piece of view.

Comment: can we fetch controller data to view by using fetch()

Comment: you set controller data to view via $this->set() in controller.

Comment: think in MVC pattern.

Comment: I mean .. in controller--$this->set('post',$post); in view $this->fetch('$c','$post') like this...can we fetch data

Comment: $post is already in your view when you call $this->set('post',$post)

Answer (score 2):

You can learn lots from this online book/page:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html

1. View Templates
2. Extending Views

   1. Using view blocks
   2. Displaying blocks
   3. Using blocks for script and CSS files
3. Layouts

   1. Using layouts from plugins
4. Elements

   1. Passing Variables into an Element
   2. Caching Elements
5. Requesting Elements from a Plugin
6. Creating your own view classes
7. View API

---

Hope it will help you!

Comment: It's a good link.  The answer should be expanded a bit, maybe